# Where should i put httpRequests in CQRS architecture using NestJs?

Tags: domain-driven-design, microservices, nestjs, cqrs

so am new to **CQRS** and **DDD** and am working on a microservice architecture using **Nestjs**, am having this problem, well i work on an **order Microservice** in which i receive an order object from the client through the controller and i pass it to the **command** to handle it but i need first to check if the data that comes with the order object is correct or no so i need to check it in **other microservices** because we don't use a shared data layer each microservice has it's own data layer for example (the object has a client Id and Name i need to cheque if the client really exists in the microservice authentication database using httpRequests... ) so in which layer should i put my **httpRequest** is it in the OrderCommandHandler or should i do the check in the Controller layer creating a checkService ?
i want to know the best practice.

Answer (score 1):

Making a synchronous web request when using microservices isn't the ideal situation it's made up to be, by a lot of companies providing middleware services. The reason is that this introduces temporal coupling between the two services; if your dependency is down or not servicing, the request you have fails.

A better solutions which adheres to DDD sligtly better is to consider what is the actual process that you have and see the responsibilities that exist. Generally when you do that you end up with BC boundaries (which tranlsate to microservice API surface), which are more cohesinve and generally able to fulfill an action completely.

The three options I see from the very little information you have here are:

1. Split the processing into two parts:

   1. One part receives an "OrderRequestes" command and validates it according to your business requirements and then fires an "OrderValidated" event
   2. Another part of your system picks up the "OrderValidates" event and processes it with the implicit assumption that data there are already validated to be fine
2. Put a copy of the subset of the data which you need in order to do validation inside of the service that would handle the order request. This is a very natural solution if there is no issue to duplicate the data locally and if it's not a problem if it's a bit stale
3. If you need to be as consistent as possible, design the process so that the service that is doing the order processing *owns* the data it needs in order to do validation on top of processing. Please note that from experience while on the surface people would ask to be as immediately consistent as possible, in reality this isn't always a real concern, and one of the above solutions would be much easier to implement and support. (also think what would happen in your case if you used a web request to validate the order, but after you return the validation result, and before the order was processed, something changed so the order wouldn't be valid any longer)